# using struct array as parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, parameters

I'm having trouble while building this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define N 3

struct cliente
{
    char nocliente[12];
    int edad;
    int precio;        
};

void imprimir(cliente *cliente1[N]);

int main()
{
    struct cliente cliente1[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese el nombre del cliente %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &cliente1[i].nocliente);
        printf("\nIngrese la edad del cliente %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &cliente1[i].edad);
        printf("\nIngrese el precio del articulo del cliente %d\n",  i+1);
        scanf("%d\n", &cliente1[i].precio);
    }

    imprimir(&cliente1[N]);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void imprimir(cliente *cliente1[N])
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    { 
        printf("%s", cliente1[i]->nocliente);
        printf("\n%d", cliente1[i]->edad);
        printf("\n%d", cliente1[i]->precio);
    }
}
```

This is the error the compiler outputs:

```
cannot convert `cliente*` to `cliente**` for argument `1` to `void imprimir(cliente**)`
```

I´ve tried declaring `(cliente *cliente[])` in the parameters of the prototype and definition but the function but it doesn't work either

Comment: Your parameter to `imprimir` should be `cliente client1[]`, and its usage within appropriately adjusted. And it should be invoked from `main` with simply `imprimir(cliente1);`. Perhaps some more time in your text/tutorial on arrays, pointers, their similarities, and differences, may help.

Comment: And then this is not c++ . Please tag it as "C"

Comment: @Jagannath There is *one* thing in this code that requires C++ to compile: `struct cliente { ... };`, then later usage of type `cliente` without the reserved word `struct` and without a formal typedef to `cliente` would fail to compile using C.

Comment: @Whozcraig oh didn't realize. Then it's a perfect c++ code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The correct (and confusing) syntax is

  ```
  void imprimir(/* const */ cliente (&cliente1)[N]);
  ```

  and then call it

  ```
  imprimir(cliente1);
  ```
- A simpler syntax:

  ```
  void imprimir(/* const */ cliente *cliente1, std::size_t size);
  ```

  with a call

  ```
  imprimir(cliente1, N);
  ```
- using class may help as `std::vector` or `std::array`

  ```
  std::array<cliente, N> cliente1;
  imprimir(/* const */ std::array<cliente, N>& cliente1);
  ```

  And call it

  ```
  imprimir(cliente1);
  ```

Note: I added `const` in comment as the array is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead :

```
void imprimir(cliente *cliente1)
```

for your function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to ...

```
imprimir(&cliente1);//you are passing the whole thing not just #3


void imprimir(cliente *cliente1) //drop the N
```